# How to prevent FF close websocket connection on ESC

Tags: firefox, websocket

There is know bug where Firefox closes the open websocket connection when the user presses ESC button.
Is there a workaround or small jQuery code that can help me to prevent that?
I was thinking to start a new websocket connection every time the current connection is being closed, but that seems a little dangerous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676881 where this problem and a partial fix is discussed. The following snippet executed after the page is loaded works for me:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
    // check for escape key
    if (event.which == 27) {
        // the following seems to fix the symptom but only in case the document has the focus
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=614304 This will be fixed in Firefox 20.